# Is did so love idiomatic?

Tags: phrase-usage, british-english

From tressure at an island - enid blyton

They did so love the house at Polseath.

Is that sentence idiomatic according to the 21st century British English? If not, what is?

Comment: As the current answer suggests, you should really specify what time period and variety of English you're looking for an answer for. But as a rule of thumb, almost any published book will contain English idiomatic for the time and place it was published in.

Answer (score 3):

The construction goes way back. From John 3:16, "For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life."

However, in this case, the "they did so (verb, usually love or want)" phrasing is very much British English, and as far as I know (I'm American) is not used much any more. Blyton was British, and writing in the 1930s, so the style is a bit dated.